# Infinite load on Firefox: transferring data from maps.googleapis.com

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When I load the site I'm working on, all is fine on all browsers except Firefox, which hangs on `Transferring data from maps.googleapis.com...`

The Google Map is rendered perfectly, but FF doesn't stop loading.

This is a big problem for me, because I have `jQuery(window).load` functions going.

Has anyone a clue how to solve this?

Comment: you may load the map asynchronously, this will not prevent the load-event from firing when there is some problem with the maps-API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API

Comment: Thanks. I did how you told me and the problem has been solved!

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't understand from your comment how you fixed it. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: @IoanaMarcu Have a look at your console output when you load your page. Google Chrome has a good console window for troubleshooting. Look for errors and warnings. Maybe one of the items listed is the source of your problem.

Comment: I tried on other browsers, the problem was not there.. Then I tried on a new private window in Firefox itself, then also the problem is not there. Then i tried clearing everything and tried again in the original browser(not private window), but the problem is still there.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});
```

Do this:

```
<body onload="initialize();">
```

As Google Instructions tell you to do!
This solved it for me.

Comment: Can you provide a link to Google's documentation?

Comment: This may no longer be true, but take a look at the asynchronous load, and the new way to load Google Maps API, without needing to have initialize() function. Looks like initMap() loads automatically now: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial - same link as in the first comment of the original question. Check out the Hello World example on the page.

Answer (score -3):

You just need to update Firefox.

Comment: Do you have any indication/proof that your assumption holds?